# Keep getting render error in React app related to React.DOM and one of my components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

For some reason, I have been getting an error related to rendering one of my components. The error says:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Home`.
▶ 30 stack frames were collapsed.
./src/index.js
src/index.js:22
  19 |   }
  20 | }
  21 | 
> 22 | ReactDOM.render(
  23 |   <App />,
  24 |   document.getElementById('root')
  25 | );
```

Here is my home.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Form from './components/Form/Form';
import NewMovies from './components/NewMovies/NewMovies';

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="container">
        <Header />
        <Form />
        <NewMovies />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

and here is my index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './home';
import Movie from './components/Movie/Movie';
import './index.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log('Made by Shahram');
    return(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={Home} /> 
          <Route path="/movie/:id" component={Movie} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "movies-with-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  },
```

home.js and index.js are in the same level in the src folder of my app. If anyone could help me with this I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Is there any export in your Movie component?

Comment: Probably need to see the code for header/form/movies as well. Take note of the error message "You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports."

Comment: You have to need the export your App class

Comment: Thank you guys! I figured it out. I can't believe I missed this but I forgot to export my movie component. I even double checked all the files but somehow I missed that.